# Math equation user input validation

Tags: c

I got task to check math equation for example: x^3+(2x-23 -> needs to report an error and correct the mistake in x^3+(2*x-23).

I need help with doing proper logic to solve this problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to implement a simple parser to convert the equation string to AST.

First step is lexical analysis, convert the equation string into a list of tokens.

Next step is grammar analysis, you can write a top-down parser to do that. But before that, it's better to properly define your equation grammar formally, using notations like BNF.

(If you only need to verify it, not computing the end result, better use a third party library.)